# Group theory cycles question error

Tags: group-theory

In a solution to a question, there is a line that reads in the group $S_{10}$: $$(1,8,2,5)^2 = (1,2,8,5)$$.

It is surely not meant to read: $$(1,8,2,5)^2 = (1,2)(5,8)$$ or am I mistaken about how cycles work?

Comment: No, you're right. It must be a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, $(1825)^2 = (12)(58)$, and the solution has a typo. You can check that it is a typo quickly by seeing that as $4$-cycles have order $4$, squaring any $4$-cycle must give an element of order $2$, and so one can never obtain a $4$-cycle by squaring a $4$-cycle.